# Find all integers $m$ and positive integers $n > 1$ so that $m + \sum_{k=1}^n x^k/k!$ has a rational root

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, roots

If $m = 1$, then $m + \sum_{k=1}^n x^k/k!$ has no rational root for $n > 1$. And clearly the polynomial has a rational foot for all integers $m$ if $n = 1$. So, besides those cases, for what integers $m$ and positive integers $n > 1$ does $m + \sum_{k=1}^n x^k/k!$ have a rational root?

I'd be fine with a somewhat vague characterization as long as it captures all of the cases and leads to a decision procedure. E.g. something like $m,n$ satisfy $m = -\sum_{k=1}^n x^k/k!$ where $x$ is an integer such that $k!$ divides $x^k$ for all $k$ such that $1 \leq k \leq n$.

Comment: Here's a simple case. The root is $ x = n!$, and clearly $m$ will be an integer.

Comment: What you ask for is almost true: $m, n$ must satisfy $m=-\sum_{k=1}^{n}{\frac{a^k}{k!}}$ for some integer $a$. This is because if the polynomial $p(x)=m+\sum_{k=1}^{n}{\frac{x^k}{k!}}$ has a rational root $x=a$, then $q(x)=n!p(x)$ has a rational root $x=a$. However by the rational root test applied to $q(x)$, $a$ must be an integer.

Comment: On the other hand, it is not true that $k! \mid a^k$ for all $k$ such that $1 \leq k \leq n$; take for example $m=n=3, a=-3$.